# Can I move app service and dependencies between subscriptions?

Tags: azure

I am using the Azure Resource Mover under preview.azure.portal to move an app service and its dependencies between subscriptions but keep encountering the following error:

{"code":"ResourceMoveProviderValidationFailed","target":"Microsoft.Web/sites","message":"{"Code":"BadRequest","Message":"Please select all the Microsoft.Web resources from 'SourceTestRG
resource group for cross-subscription migration.
Also, please ensure destination resource group 'DestTestRG'
doesn't have any Microsoft.Web resources before move operation.
Here is the list of resources you have to move together: AzureTestAppTest (Microsoft.Web/sites).
This resource is located in resource group 'SourceTestRG',
but hosted in the resource group 'AppsRG'. This may be a result of prior move operations.

The destination RG 'DestTestRG'  does not have any resources.
Any ideas on what may be the issue ?

UPDATE:

So basically the process is as follows ?

Create an App service plan lets say MainAppServicePlan in a ResourceGroup lets say ASPRG1 under subscription MainSub1

You can create resources in different resource groups for example:

```
  App Service: AppService1 in ResourceGroup RGApp1
  App Service: AppService2 in ResourceGroup RGApp2
  App Service: AppService3 in ResourceGroup RGApp3
```

But thay all are under the App Service Plan ASPRG1.
That means if i try to move from AppService1 from MainSub1 to MainSub2 it will give an error
because i am required to move AppService2 and AppService3, is that correct ?

If that is the case , wouldn't it be feasible to create a brand new App Service Plan and move AppService1 to that new
AppService Plan and then since no other resource resides in that App Servie Plan then the cross subscription migration should be ok ?
Can the app service plan be changed once it is already set on an app service ?

Comment: Based on the error it says you didn't select to move AzureTestAppTest together with your resource group

Comment: I have selected the actual App Service . Just thinking it sits in the App Service Plan , SourceServicePlan, do i need to move the App Service Plan as well and all resources in the app service plan.  Also the app service as it says was originally created by the resource group AppsRG, so does that mean I must  move all the resources in the originating resource group of AppsRG ?   If so would it be feasible to move the app service to a different service plan and then try a migration ?

Comment: Either move it to a different plan or align the app to the same rg. On a side note I'd steer from the portal towards the CLI. Anything complicated and the portal breaks for unknown reasons. But this maybe an advice for future endeavors as it takes time to figure out the CLI.

Comment: Something is not working correctly. I have created a band new App Service Plan under a resource group RG1. The app service is under that plan and the same resource group. I try to move across subscriptions and still the same error. The location of both service plans is north central us ?

Comment: I hit the same thing. I have two AppServices that got created in the same ResourceGroup. I want them in different groups now but I'm running into this limitation. I tried creating a new AppServicePlan as you suggest and moving one AppService to it. But I'm still told all AppServices within the ResourceGroup must move together. (This is attempting to move the AppService to a new ResourceGroup in a new Subscription).

Answer (score 1):

App Service resources and Resource Groups are tied together internally, and it's not always transparent. See the [Move guidance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/move-limitations/app-service-move-limitations) for all considerations.

Specifically:

> - All App Service resources in the resource group must be moved together.
> - App Service resources can only be moved from the resource group in which they were originally created. If an App Service resource is no
>   longer in its original resource group, move it back to its original
>   resource group. Then, move the resource across subscriptions.